# Join table with mapping of array in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to join two table, with first table contain an array which is primary keys of second table in JSON format

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=02db5f38b51753f8bed2a93359f15144)

You can use the `ANY` function:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM a
JOIN b ON a.id = ANY(ids)
```

**Edit**:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7f0f16cb359c51dbaa8f80adbdd4c51f)

If you have `jsonb` arrays, you can use the `@>` operator. Note, that this works only if your integer `id` values are cast into type `jsonb` as well. Since a type `int` is not directly castable into type `jsonb`, your need the intermediate step via type `text`, which yield the strange syntax `id::text::jsonb`:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM a
JOIN b ON b.ids @> a.id::text::jsonb
```

If your column is of type `json` instead `jsonb`, you need to cast it into type `jsonb` because otherwise the operator would not work:

```
b.ids::jsonb @> ...
```

Comment: here ids is json datatype, so when I using this query it shows ANY requires array on right side

Comment: is it possible to replace array values with related table values